# How to decide whether a function is in $H^p_+$.

Tags: functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

$H^p_+$ is the Hardy space on the upper half-plane of $\mathbb C$ consisting of functions $f$ satisfying
$$
\sup_{y_0>0}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |f(x+iy_0)|^p dx\right)^{\frac 1p}<\infty
$$
For what values of $a$ will the function $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{(z+2i)^{2a}}$ be in $H^p_+$?

This was an exam question for electric engineers, so it shouldn't be too difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z=x+i y_0$, then $|e^{iz}|=e^{-y_0}\leq 1$ and:
$$ \left|(z+2i)^{2a}\right|=\left|z+2i\right|^{2a}=\left((z+2i)(\bar{z}-2i)\right)^a=(x^2+(y_0+2)^2)^a,\tag{1}$$
hence we just need to find the values of $a$ for which:
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{(x^2+(y_0+2)^2)^{ap}}<+\infty.\tag{2}$$
That leads to $ap>\frac{1}{2}$, or just:
$$ a>\frac{1}{2p}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: I understand that the integrals are infinite when $ap=\frac12$. But how do you know that they are bounded when $ap>\frac12$?

Comment: @DávidKertész:  $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^\alpha}\leq 1+\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x^{2\alpha}}=1+\frac{1}{2\alpha-1}.$$